# segmentation fault when using tar with --listed-incremental

Tags: tar, segmentation-fault

When I run a script to invoke tar with the option "--listed-incremental", I get a segmentation fault. I have a loop with parses through 6 filesystems (a combination of ordinary partitions and LVM logical volumes), as well as one subdirectory. The first time I run the the script, everything is fine and all the tar files and snar (snapshot) files are created. The second time I run the script, it should create incremental tar files based on changes per the snar file. Every one of the filesystem backups crash with a segmentation fault, but the subdirectory backup processes okay. Here's the script output (I precede the tar call with an echo to print out the tar parameters, and print out the exit code following the tar call):

```
tar --create --one-file-system --no-check-device --auto-compress --warning=no-file-ignored --file=/home/randy/Backup/home4/pictures/update-week-40-to-43/Pictures-week-40-to-43.1.tar /home/randy/Pictures  --listed-incremental=/home/randy/Backup/home4/pictures/update-week-40-to-43/Pictures-week-40-to-43.snar

/home/randy/Backup/bkup-scripts2/source/bkupf-tar-backup.sh: line 361:  8831 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) tar "${archive_opts_a[@]}" "${file_opt}" "${source_directory}" "${exclude_opt}" "${increment_opt}" &>> "${gc_logfile}"

>>> ERROR in creating tar update.  Error value: 139
```

Line 361 is the declaration line of the function in which the tar command is located.

I can run tar without the "--listed-incremental" option and it runs just fine, with no problems. This is only a problem when I use this option.

I did some research on this and found this link

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2295549

but the person was able to solve the problem by coping a version of tar from another location. I did a clean/check/autoremove/update/upgrade, all to no effect. I have run this both in Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 3.19.0-28) and Xubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.04-43) with the same result.

I did some more research, and found a bug report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tar/+bug/687594

from 2010 stating that a bug was discovered in tar version 1.23, a patch was created, and it was fixed. Well that was 6 years ago, and I have the exact same problem now (tar version 1.28.2-1). Has the problem suddenly reappeared after all these years? I assume I'm not the only one using the "--listed-incremental" option. Is there something wrong with my command line?